# Multiple named Instances and Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups

We have a two-node multi-subnet Windows Server 2012 R2 cluster in two regions. We have three named SQL Server 2012 standalone instances on each node and are in the process of setting up Availability Groups on each SQL instance. I have set one up on one instance successfully, but when I try to set up the second AG on the second named instance I get the following error message:

> A connection timeout has occurred while attempting to establish a connection to availability replica `DPA01\BAPP01` with id `[567C-F10B-43C3-A2DB-BEDDD307589B]`. Either a networking or firewall issue exists, or the endpoint address provided for the replica is not the database mirroring endpoint of the host server instance."

It looks like it does not support multiple endpoints with different ports on a single node. Has anyone come across this scenario? First instance, I used 5023 as the end point port and for the second I used 5022. But I cannot telnet from node 2 to 1 on port 5023 whereas I can telnet from Node 1 to 2 on port 5023. Node 1 is not listening that port.

My simple question: Is the following setup supported?

> Having multiple SQL named instances on two node windows cluster and Always On Availability Groups on each Instance.

Example of my setup:

```
Node1 
Named instances: SQLINS1, SQLINS2
Availability Groups - AO1 on SQLINS1 and AO2 on SQLINST2

Node2 
Named instances: - SQLINS3, SQLINS4
Availability Groups - AO1 on SQLINS3 and AO2 on SQLINST4
```

Where:

```
Replicas of AO1: SQLINS1, SQLINS3
Replicas of AO2: SQLINS2, SQLINS4
```

If my question is not clear I am happy to give you more details about the setup which I am trying.

Answer (score 3):

Your proposed setup looks okay to me; as long as both nodes are in the same domain, that should work fine.

What you need to resolve is the ability for each server to get to the other on the configured ports. It sounds like 5023 is being blocked by a firewall rule of some kind, or that you haven't used the same port consistently throughout the configuration of *an* availability group.

I've come across the error you're showing and in my case it was actually an encryption issue. Please check out the following posts in detail:

http://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/system-configuration/troubleshooting-alwayson

http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/system-configuration/dedicated-network-availability-group

Answer (score 1):

you cannot install 2 SQL Server instances to the same WSFC node and have one instance host a replica for on Availability Group and the other instance host a replica for a different Availability Group. Instead, you would have a single SQL Server Instance on the WSFC node that would participate in both of the Availability Groups.

Possible solution

Node1 
Named instances: SQLINS1, SQLINS2
 
Availability Groups - AO1 on SQLINS1 and AO2 on SQLINST2

Node2 
Named instances: - SQLINST3
 
Availability Groups - AO1 and AO2 on SQLINST3

Comment: I don't understand where you're getting that you can't have two availability groups on two different named instances of SQL Server. Perhaps you are thinking about having the same availability group on two different *clustered* instances of SQL Server which have common potential owners inside the WSFC?

Comment: My setup is having two named instances on same host and each having two availability groups.The second node also having two named instances as replicas. I cannot get endpoint working on the second instance while first one is working fine.